# why one method running time more than other method follow the same algorithm in netbeans?

Tags: java

when implement two methods follow same algorithm , i want to calculate running time for each. but i notice that the method with less code take time more than other method.
the following is the first method with less code but take more running time:

```
 public void encryptFiles(List<BloomFilter> bfList1) {

        StopWatch watch = new StopWatch();
           watch.start("calculate time"); 
        for (BloomFilter bfList2 : bfList1) {
           Random raa = new Random();
           int g1 = raa.nextInt();
              double m1 = (double) ((double) Math.round(g1 * 10) / 10.0);

              List<double[]>  res1 = new ArrayList<>();
             double[] e1 = new double[400];
             double[] k1 = new double[400];

               Vector<Double> j = new Vector<Double>(400);
               Vector<Double> h = new Vector<Double>(400);

          String bfName= bfList2.getName();
            for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
                if (s.get(i) == 1) {
                    j.add( (double) bfList2.getBitSet().getWord(i));

                    h.add((double) bfList2.getBitSet().getWord(i));
                } else {

                    j.add(0.5 * (bfList2.getBitSet().getWord(i))+m1);
                    h.add(0.5 * (bfList2.getBitSet().getWord(i))+m1 );
                }
            }

            for (int u = 0; u < 400; u++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < 400; y++) {
                    e1[u] +=a2[u][y]*j.get(y);
                    k1[u] +=b2[u][y]*h.get(y);

                }
            }
                    res1.add(e1);
                    res1.add(k1);

            hasssh.put(bfName,res1 );
       }
             watch.stop();
          encryptedBFListInTime=watch.getTotalTimeSeconds();
        System.out.println("time only for encrypt bloom filter"+encryptedBFListInTime);
             //System.out.println("encrypt files only in "+encryptedBFListInTime);

        }
```

the other method with the same code and some extra steps but less running time:

```
  public  BloomFilterIndex encryptTree(BloomFilterIndex tree) {


          StopWatch watch1=new StopWatch();
        watch1.start("calculate");
             for(int m=0;m<tree.root.children.size();m++){

             BloomFilterIndex.BFINode<Integer> n=(BloomFilterIndex.BFINode<Integer>)tree.root.children.get(m);
              encrypt(n);
             }
            watch1.stop();
         end=watch1.getTotalTimeSeconds(); 
            System.out.println("encrypt tree only in :"+end);
        return tree;


    }
         public void encrypt(BloomFilterIndex.BFINode<Integer> root) {

        List<double[]> ress = new ArrayList<>();
          if(!root.isLeaf()){

                 c = new double[root.value.size()];

                 for (int i = 0; i < root.value.size(); i++) {

                 c[i] =root.value.getBitSet().getWord(i);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
            } 
                 ress.add(c);
                 root.value = null;
                 root.value2 = ress;


          for(BloomFilterIndex.BFINode<Integer> g:root.children)

                     encrypt(g);

          } else{

         double[] y = new double[400];
         double[] z = new double[400];
         Random r = new Random();
         Integer g1 = r.nextInt();
         double m5 = (double) ((double) Math.round(g1 * 10) / 10.0);
         Vector<Double> m6 = new Vector<Double>(400);
         Vector<Double> n1 = new Vector<Double>(400);

           for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {

                if (s.get(i) == 1) {
                    m6.add((double) root.value.getBitSet().getWord(i));
                    n1.add((double) root.value.getBitSet().getWord(i));
                } else {
                    m6.add( 0.5 * (root.value.getBitSet().getWord(i))+m5);
                    n1.add( 0.5 * (root.value.getBitSet().getWord(i))+m5 );
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 400;i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 400; j++) {
                    y[i] += a2[i][j] * m6.get(j);
                    z[i] += b2[i][j] * n1.get(j);
                }
            }
            ress.add(y);
            ress.add(z);
            root.value = null;
            root.value2 = ress;

     }

     }
i used all function to calculate running time `System.currentTimeMills()`,`Systen.nanoTime()`, `instant.now()`, `new Date.getTime(),  localTime.now()` all of thes give the same result and i try to use `JMH benchmark` but cannot running it.
```

Comment: Microbenchmarks are **very** difficult to get right. Your current approach is unlikely to produce meaningful benchmarks. And you shouldn't be using `Vector` in either case.

Comment: didn't you ask the same question a few days back?

Comment: @gagansingh lol

Comment: @Elliott Frisch what is the problem here, iam very confused or how can i solve it .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java